# Python: Start new terminal on Linux and wait for it to finish/exit

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Same situation as my other question: [Python: Start new command prompt on Windows and wait for it finish/exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit) except that I need it to work on Linux.

If you don't feel like reading the other question: I want to open some new terminal windows and have each execute a command, and I want the parent python program to wait until all the terminal windows are closed.

Doing:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e {command}")
```

Opens a new terminal window but the program doesn't wait. Using `p = Popen()` and `p.wait()` doesn't work because the gnome-terminal command completes instantly.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but the preferred way to start a terminal in Ubuntu is to run `x-terminal-emulator`; that will run whatever is considered the default terminal emulator on the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnome-terminal reuses the same parent process for all terminal windows.

Use `gnome-terminal --disable-factory` to force it to start a new process.

Comment: I saw that but it wasn't working, then I realized it's because I was doing `Popen(..., shell=True)`. Thanks

Comment: My little test doesn't work: `gnome-terminal --disable-factory -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3"`

Comment: @imallett works fine (still!) for me on Centos 6 with gnome-terminal 2.31.3

Comment: A version issue, maybe? I tested on Ubuntu 15.04 with gnome-terminal _3.14.2_.

Comment: @imallett almost certainly; GNOME is the poster child for the [CADT model](http://www.jwz.org/doc/cadt.html). I don't have GNOME 3 here so can't help; you might want to ask a new question here or on the [Ubuntu stack exchange](http://askubuntu.com/) specifying that you need it to work in GNOME 3.

Comment: [Done](http://askubuntu.com/q/627019/170801). I suggest you track it and backpropogate into this answer for the benefit of people-of-the-future.