# Invoke developer command prompt from python

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.4, peverify

How can I invoke a `Developer Command Prompt` that comes with `Visual Studio 2013` and execute my `peverify` commands in it from a python script. I am using python 3.4. I was able to execute commands in  `windows command prompt` using `subprocess` but dont know how to do so from Developer Command Prompt.

Please help me out.My aim is to execute `peverify` command through a set of files in a given directory.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need is simply start

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
```

Comment: Yes..you are right. But how to get it done via python??

Answer (score -1):

Here's one of the many ways to call it.

```
from subprocess import call
call(%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"", shell=True)
```

It can also be done with os.system() and quite a few others from subprocess depending on your needs.