# How to run multiple commands via START command

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have a case where I need to spawn multiple `CMD` instances (using the `START` program), and each instance needs to run some commands *in sequence*. These commands are generated by a batch script, so they are not known ahead of time.

Basically, what I'm looking to do is something like the following, but I don't know the proper syntax (or if it's even possible):

`START (program_a && program_b && program_c)`

Obviously, those parentheses are incorrect syntax. So when I try to run some syntactically correct variant(s):

`START program_a && program_b && program_c`

I just end up with one `CMD` instance being spawned, running `program_a`, and the "owning" batch script continues to execute `program_b` and `program_c` on its own (i.e. *not* in the `CMD` instance spawned by `START`).

Comment: Put several Start commands on their own line. Why do they have to be executed in the same cmd process ? Why not create a second batch dynamically that calls those programs ?

Comment: Because the tasks cannot be parallelized. They must be run in sequence.

Comment: @Marged suggested that you dynamically create a subsidiary batch file containing the three critical lines on separate physical lines, then `start` the subsidiary batch. *That* would run the three commands in sequence. You should add the `/wait` switch to the `start` if you want the main batch to wait for the subsidiary batch to finish.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think, you need something like:

```
start "MyWindow" cmd /c "ping localhost & ipconfig & pause"
```

Comment: That's not work for me because one command need quotes also like `dir "c:\foo 1"`.

Comment: @gotwo: Where's the problem? `start "MyWindow" cmd /c "ping localhost & dir "c:\foo 1" & pause"`. see `cmd /?` for how it treats quotes.

Comment: @ Stephan, yes you are right. There may be a mistake in my test before. `dir...` should be a simpler example on my actual topic with Powershell. Again a simplified example: `start "MyWindow" cmd /k "ping localhost & powershell -command "&{$host|gm}" & pause"` does not work for me. `powershell -command "&{$host|gm}"` works as expected. I have described here the solution.

Comment: @gotwo: Batch syntax/escaping special chars sometimes is a bit unintuitive: `start "MyWindow" cmd /k "ping localhost & powershell -command "^&{$host^|gm}" & pause"`

Answer (score 8):

It helps to escape every `&` with `^&`:

```
START program_a ^&^& program_b ^&^& program_c
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score -1):

Trying in a batch file, but the two commands (!vexe! and move) are executed at the same time :

```
start "" /d "!mpwd!" /low /affinity !hex! /b cmd /v:on /c " 1^>"%lcpu%.!cnxt!" 2^>^&1 !vexe! !vcmd! && move /y "%%a" "!mrel!" "
```

Tried with escaping the && or not, putting the move into parenthesis as well. No luck there...

Any advice ?

Comment: Btw, since then I've found the way to make it work : https://github.com/Kochise/batch-makeit/blob/master/makeit.bat#L1152