# Open Empty Command Prompt and Stay Open with Python

Tags: python, shell, cmd, os.system

I want python to open an empty Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and leave it open without running anything. I want command prompt to open in a new window and this python code to continue running.

I have tried:

```
os.system("start C://Windows/System32/cmd.exe")
```

And:

```
os.system("C://Windows/System32/cmd.exe")
```

And:

```
os.system("start /wait C://Windows/System32/cmd.exe")
```

And:

```
os.system("start /wait cmd /c")
```

None of the above left Command Prompt open. I also want to be able to close it later (with python) by using:

```
os.system("taskkill /f /im  cmd.exe")
```

Thanks for any help. I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit) was the closest but this needed a command to be entered. I don't want a command to be entered before.

Comment: For me, the following work perfectly: `os.system('cmd /C start cmd')`, `os.system('cmd /C start')`, `os.system('start cmd')`, `os.system('start')`

Comment: By the way: why did you [delete the other equal question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44245619) and post a new one??

Comment: @aschipfl Because the person who posted the answer on that deleted it, before I had copied the code and it was not going to get any more attention afterwards.

Comment: At first, be more patient; good answers may need some time. To get more attraction, edit and improve your original question post regarding the comments, instead of deleting and reposting! Also consider to start a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Note that reposting might attract down-votes and close-votes...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks. I'll keep that in mind for next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a few ways to do this. Firstly, there are 2 ways of opening command prompt. One is the normal Windows Command Prompt.The other way is by opening it with python as the input. There are a few ways for both.

**For Python as the input:**

```
os.system('cmd.exe /C start "Unique_name" cmd.exe')
```

The "unique_name" is so that it can be closed with:

```
os.system('taskkill /F /IM "cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Unique_name"')
```

---

The following also work:

`os.system('cmd /C start cmd')`

`os.system('cmd /C start')`

`os.system('start cmd')`

---

---

***For Windows Command Prompt:***

```
os.startfile("C://Windows/System32/cmd.exe")
```

This can be closed with:

```
os.system("taskkill /f /im  cmd.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked (Windows 10, Python 3.3.5 and using the psutil library).

```
import psutil
import subprocess
import time
import os

p = subprocess.Popen("start /wait cmd.exe", shell=True)
# the pid of p is the pid of the shell, so let's get the shell's children,
# i.e. the opened cmd.exe window
p2 = psutil.Process(p.pid)

# there should be exactily one child
# but it may not have been started yet
while True:
    children = p2.children()
    if children:
        break
    print("no children yet")
    time.sleep(0.01)

print(children)
time.sleep(5)

for child in children:
    child.kill()

p.wait()
```