# How can I manipulate cmd prompt from python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

Is possible to manipulate cmd window from python without closing it everytime I send a new command? 
I would like to manipulate it as I do with keyboard, command by command, with command prompt opened, so I could see outputs.

For now I'm using this, but is not what I want...

```
subprocess.Popen('start dir', shell=True)
```

Comment: `import os;os.system("cmd1;cmd2;cmd3")`, use semicolons and os

Comment: you should explain a little better what you want to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Start new command prompt on Windows and wait for it finish/exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit)

Comment: You probably need to capture the stdIn and standard out.  This discussion might help: https://gist.github.com/waylan/2353749