# Python : Execute several commands in CMD in single instance

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to call several "blocking" .bat files from my python program. First thing I need to do is change the directory that the CMD is opened. After I have the CMD pointing to the desired location I will call two bat files. I want them to execute sequentially.

```
def launchAdminConsole():    
    print('Going to launch admin console')
    changeDir = 'cd dir1\\dir2\\bin \n 1.bat \n 2.bat'
    os.system("start /wait cmd /c {"+changeDir+"}")
    print("Admin Console launced")
```

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit) using the `/wait` should make the command prompt wait but for me, it just pops up and goes away so I am not sure if the bat file is executed or not.

Also I am not sure if I have formed the command line code correctly. I googled about how to execute several commands in a single instance of cmd from python but none of the results helped me much so I took a guess on my own and did the above code.

I need the command prompt to open and run the two bat files and then give the control back to python. I do not need to fetch the output of the bat files or something I just need to know if the two files are executed or not. As I said before they are all blocking bat files so if run correctly the command prompt will not be able to close so quickly. I hope you guys got my requirement else comment below I will explain more.

Edit : 
Updated my code as follows

```
def launchAdminConsole2():
    print('Going to launch admin console')
    changeDir = 'cd dir1\\dir2\\bin'
    runOnce1 = '1.bat'
    runOnce2 = '2.bat'
    p = subprocess.Popen(changeDir,shell=True)
    p.wait()
    print(p.returncode)
    p = subprocess.call([changeDir, runOnce, runOnce1])
    p.wait()
    print("Admin Console launced")
```

The return code for the change directory returns `0` but it is saying that `1.bat` is not found. I am sure that if the directory has changed that file will be present in the given location.

The error is

```
 File "C:\Users\nirma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 304, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\nirma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\nirma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run several commands using `cmd.exe /c` if you separate them with **ampersand**s:

```
cmd.exe /c "cd \dir & 1.bat & 2.bat"
```

Try passing that to subprocess.call and see how it goes.

Comment: Considering that `\ ` effectively means root, `cd \dir` suggests you're changing directory to one named `dir` in the root of the current drive. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Fair point.  The `cd` command should be given the real path, either relative or absolute.

Comment: @Compo The user will be giving the location of dir. It is not mandatory that it should be in the same drive. However I am using the command combination mentioned above and some simple if statements to decide which drive I am currently in and which drive to choose to. If there is any other way to do this more efficiently then do let me know

Comment: @NirmalRaj, the directory appears to be hard coded within your 'python program', not provided by the user. If the user is providing it somewhere in the process then there should be some form of coding to verify it as a genuine and existing path, preferably at some stage early on, _read as in your python program_. For that reason you should be concentrating on getting your python code correct, the [batch-file] and [cmd] tags are currently irrelevant to your question, and their addition makes your question too broad.

Comment: @Compo In the sample I have posted above the directory is hardcoded. In my actual code I have modified it to work with user given inputs. As you suggested this is making the question broad so I will start another thread with this question. The current is what I came looking for and I found it. Thanks