# How to open a sub screen with a python CLI?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

When using text editors in the console, it seems that a "sub screen" is entered. Once the user terminates, they are returned to the orignal command line. In that sub screen the screen can be cleared, for example. How can I write a python CLI with that functionality?

Basically I want the User to start the program and the command line shall be cleared. When exiting the program, the original command line with its history shall be shown again.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit