# Run python function in command prompt launched from tkinter present in standalone pyinstaller exe

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, command-line, pyinstaller

There is a python program having functions e.g.  function1 , function2 and tkinter-function . The whole program has been converted into a standalone exe using pyinstaller.

On Launching, the program creates gui using tkinter. In tkinter window, two buttons are presented to user. The user chooses anyone of them, this action launches a separate command prompt which runs the desired function e.g. function1 present in the same file and asks the user for entering data in command prompt.

I want to run the chosen function in a separate command prompt window, as this shows the progress of the running function. All the python files and dependencies are present in single pyinstaller exe.

How to launch a command prompt running desired function when the main program is in pyinstaller exe ?

*mainprogram.py*

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk  as ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Program GUI")
window.geometry("150x150") 


def function1():
    data=input(' Enter Data:')
    print(data)
    
def function2():
    data=input(' Enter MoreData:')
    print(data)


def RunFunc1():
    print('Running ... Function1',)
    function1()      
def RunFunc2():
    print('Running ... Function1',)
    function2()
   
button = tk.Button( text="Function1", command=RunFunc1, width=15, height=5, bg="blue", fg="yellow" ).pack()
button = tk.Button( text="Function2", command=RunFunc2, width=15, height=5, bg="blue", fg="yellow" ).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What the point of using console input in a GUI application?

Comment: My functions i.e. function1 & function2 are command line based. I am using tkinter just to launch them ( I could not find any way to show command line output in tkinter window with real time update). So I want show the running progress of the chosen function in a separate command prompt.

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit)?