# Opening Anaconda Prompt with python

Tags: python, operating-system, command

I want to create a script that will help me with installing packages for Spyder. Therefore, I want to use Python and have the script first open Anaconda Prompt, then execute the commands and then close that window.

However, I can get it to open for example the calculator but it doesn't seem to open the command prompt. For opening the calculator I used:

```
import os
os.popen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe")
```

How can I get it to open the command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to combine a little knowledge of Windows batch language, some guidance from [a previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615580/8896374), and extract key information from your specific Windows Start Menu shortcut which you would typically use to fire up the Anaconda Prompt.

First, from the Start Menu, right-click on the "Anaconda Prompt" shortcut and select "Open file location". In File Explorer, right-click on the shortcut file and open its Properties. In the Shortcut tab, take a close look at the command in the "Target:" field. If you were to run this command in a Command Prompt window, it should turn that Command Prompt window into an Anaconda Prompt for all intents and purposes.

We just need the part of the command in the "Target:" field that is after the call to `cmd.exe "/K"`. It should look something like this, calling an `activate.bat` file within the Anaconda install directory (or "[miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)", the slimmer version which I use):

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\%USERNAME%\miniconda3
```

The argument `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\miniconda3` determines the specific Conda environment that is loaded upon startup of the Anaconda Prompt. Keeping it as a path to the base `miniconda3` folder will load the "base" environment, the default when you fire up your Anaconda Prompt from the Start Menu shortcut. If you would like to load a different environment, make this a path to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\miniconda3\envs\custom-env-name` instead (point being, append `\envs\custom-env-name` to your Anaconda/miniconda install dir).

For the purpose of this example, let's refer to [this text of two paths that runs `activate.bat` to the designated Conda environment] as `START_ANACONDA_CMD`. As for the command(s) you want to run to install packages in the designated Conda environment, let's call those `PACKAGE_INSTALL_CMD_1` and `PACKAGE_INSTALL_CMD_2`.

The `os.system` call you should try executing from Python is as follows:

```
os.system(r"""start "My Spyder Package Installer" /wait cmd /c "START_ANACONDA_CMD&PACKAGE_INSTALL_CMD_1&PACKAGE_INSTALL_CMD_2" """)
```

Notes:

- See [Microsoft docs on the `start` program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) for more optional arguments to the `start` call. Specifying a title for the new Command Prompt window as I did in the example may be nice, but not necessary.
- From [Microsoft docs on the `cmd` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), the function of `cmd /c` is to:

> Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.

- Run a series of commands with `cmd /c` by concatenating the commands with the `&` character. Do not put additional `"` quotes around the commands beyond what is shown in the example.
- I wrap the entire `os.system` command string in `r""" """` because otherwise you would have to escape `"` quotes and any backslashes in paths.

Once you have your `START_ANACONDA_CMD`, a nice little test is to open a Python interpreter and run the following:

```
os.system(r"""start /wait cmd /c "START_ANACONDA_CMD&conda info&timeout /t 10" """)
```

This should open a Command Prompt window to the designated Conda environment, run `conda info`, and then wait 10 seconds before exiting.

Comment: thank you very much for both the clear explanation as well as providing a working example. I've been able to open Conda Prompt from my Python interpreter.

Comment: @QtyPython2020 I'm glad I could help! If it answered your question, please mark my answer as the accepted answer when you have a chance.