# How to open a CMD window using python code

Tags: python, cmd

I want to open a cmd window using Python. I think I can use os library but I don't know how.

Comment: Do you just want to open a cmd window? Or do you want to execute a cmd command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Start new command prompt on Windows and wait for it finish/exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import os
 os.system("start cmd.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Python: Start new command prompt on Windows and wait for it finish/exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit)

```
import os
os.system("start /wait cmd /c cmd")
```

Should do the trick!